# IO Error in Android

Tags: android

I am connecting to a php page via httppost in Android. I am getting an IOException.
I am running in localhost. What is the reason for this? Please help.
The code is like this.

```
    htClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    httpPost = new HttpPost("http://localhost/form/android_test.php");
    response = new BasicResponseHandler();
    try
    {           
        result = htClient.execute(httpPost,response);
        Toast.makeText(active.this,result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    catch (ClientProtocolException e) {

        Toast.makeText(active.this,e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) {
    // i am always getting this exception.  
         Toast.makeText(active.this,"IO Error " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try [`10.0.2.2`](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/emulator.html) instead of localhost.